# How to add another data summary to PIVOT query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on creating a PIVOT query in SQL Server.  I have succeeded in creating the PIVOT query detailed below:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT ITM_VAL_NUM, YR, PRVDR_NUM
FROM     dbo.newfile
WHERE  (PRVDR_NUM = '410007') AND (WKSHT_CD = 'B000001') AND (LINE_NUM BETWEEN '00100' AND '02399') AND (CLMN_NUM = '00000') 
) t
PIVOT(
         SUM(ITM_VAL_NUM) 
         FOR YR IN (
         [2020],
         [2019],
         [2018],
         [2017])
) AS pivot_table;
```

| PRVDR_NUM | LINE_NUM | 2020 | 2019 | 2018 | 2017 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 410007 | 00100-02399 | 8463 | 4180 | 570 | 888 |

I would like to expand the above PIVOT query to sum several rows of data based on row numbers.  For example, the result above is for LINE_NUM 00100-02399. I would like to add another series of
LINE_NUM from 03000-04699. I have tried (1) a joined table (2) using AND or OR without any luck.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT ITM_VAL_NUM, YR, PRVDR_NUM
FROM     dbo.newfile
WHERE  (PRVDR_NUM = '410007') AND (WKSHT_CD = 'B000001') AND (LINE_NUM BETWEEN '00100' AND '02399') AND (CLMN_NUM = '00000') 
OR (PRVDR_NUM = '410007') AND (WKSHT_CD = 'B000001') AND (LINE_NUM BETWEEN '03000 AND '04699) AND (CLMN_NUM = '00000')
) t
PIVOT(
         SUM(ITM_VAL_NUM) 
         FOR YR IN (
         [2020],
         [2019],
         [2018],
         [2017],
         [2016],
         [2015])
) AS pivot_table;
```

The desired outcome is as follows:

| PRVDR_NUM | LINE_NUM | 2020 | 2019 | 2018 | 2017 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 410007 | 00100-02399 | 8463 | 4180 | 570 | 888 |
| 410007 | 03000-04699 | number | number | number | number |

Thank you for taking the time to and answer my question.

Comment: You don't specify LINE_NUM in your output.

Comment: One way would be to create all the variations of desired line_num ranges and inner join those representations, but also including the LINE_NUM range label in the select statement.

Comment: Should have mentioned that when I did include the LINE_NUM in the select statement, the query retrieved each individual line between 00100 and 02399.  My goal is a PIVOT query that sums the values for each line included in the 00100-02399 range.  Thank you for comment

Comment: I added fiddle below. The idea is to display the range label. The sum by year will aggregate by year the values withing your selections.

Comment: Thank you.  Will work on this afternoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this will compile, because you did not post your data, however, you can see if it will create a result that you are looking for.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e3dcd0/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE newfile (PRVDR_NUM NVARCHAR(20),LINE_NUM NVARCHAR(20), ITM_VAL_NUM INT, YR INT)
INSERT newfile VALUES
('410007','00101',10,2020),
('410007','02000',10,2020),
('410007','00101',10,2019),
('410007','02100',10,2019),
('410007','00201',10,2018),
('410007','02700',10,2018),
('410007','00111',10,2017),
('410007','02400',10,2017),

('410007','03101',10,2020),
('410007','03300',10,2020),
('410007','04001',10,2019),
('410007','03100',10,2019),
('410007','03201',10,2018),
('410007','03700',10,2018),
('410007','03111',10,2017),
('410007','03400',10,2017)
```

**Query 1**:

```
CREATE TABLE #LINE_NUM_RANGE (LINE_NUM_START NVARCHAR(20),LINE_NUM_END NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT #LINE_NUM_RANGE VALUES
('00100','02399'),
('03000','04699')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e3dcd0/1/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT ITM_VAL_NUM, YR, PRVDR_NUM,LINE_NUM = R.LINE_NUM_START+'-'+R.LINE_NUM_END
FROM     newfile
INNER JOIN #LINE_NUM_RANGE R ON LINE_NUM  BETWEEN R.LINE_NUM_START AND LINE_NUM_END
WHERE  (PRVDR_NUM = '410007') --AND (WKSHT_CD = 'B000001') AND (CLMN_NUM = '00000') OR (PRVDR_NUM = '410007') AND (WKSHT_CD = 'B000001') 

) t
PIVOT(
         SUM(ITM_VAL_NUM) 
         FOR YR IN (
         [2020],
         [2019],
         [2018],
         [2017],
         [2016],
         [2015])
) AS pivot_table
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e3dcd0/1/1)**:

```
| PRVDR_NUM |    LINE_NUM | 2020 | 2019 | 2018 | 2017 |   2016 |   2015 |
|-----------|-------------|------|------|------|------|--------|--------|
|    410007 | 00100-02399 |   20 |   20 |   10 |   10 | (null) | (null) |
|    410007 | 03000-04699 |   20 |   20 |   20 |   20 | (null) | (null) |
```